# XML category update ignored + Manadev filter problem - Magento 1.9 Lesti FPC 1.4.8

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, lesti-fpc

For one category I created this xml update:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
  <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>200</limit></action>
  <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>200</limit></action>
</reference>
```

This works okay when FPC is turned off. When it is turned on and we refresh one or two times the update is ignored.

We have the same kind of problem on the layered navigation. Using it after cache refresh, all works okay. Refreshing the filter, for example click on an attribute, then deselect it and select it again and it doesn't work anymore.

Who can help? The problem is driving me nuts.

It looks like it only happens on productcollection. The filter is still selected..but shows an unfiltered productcollection.

All configuration is done well, I rechecked this multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it. Very stupid. I totally debugged it and found that productlist was in lazy blocks config of Lesti FPC. :D hope I did not waste anybody's time. And maybe I can help someone with the answer.